# vb6, Call entry point of dynamically load dll, last step

Tags: dll, vb6

I want to load a dll dynamically and call a function of this dll (VB6).

The function "getservice" takes 2 Longs and returns a Long (it is an ID for a service).

So far I have the lines:

```
Private Declare Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" ...
Private Declare Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" ...

Dim lib_timing As Long
Dim pa_getservice As Long

lib_timing = LoadLibrary("l:\abc\runtime\mvc_timing.dll)
pa_getservice = GetProcAddress(lib_timing, "getservice")
```

Now, I do not know how to call the getservice function of lib_timing

```
call pa_getservice ??? or
call .. (..)
```

I have seen the stackoverflow question number 1667397, but I do not understand the last part, how I can use this for my call.

I now have - from GetProcAddress - this long. But what do I do with this long in order to call the function of my own dll?

Thanks alot in advance for all helpful information

Wolfgang

Comment: I take that mvc_timing.dll does not support COM then?

Comment: What do you mean by "support COM"?

Comment: Oh dear, you've been downvoted by Hans, have a plus from me to make up for his rudeness

Comment: I wrote the dll, but I do not know the SYNTAX to call the function!

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667397/accessing-dynamically-loaded-dll-with-loadlibrary-in-visual-basic-6

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the DLL you are calling does not support COM and thus late binding to it my solution to problems like this is to write a small .NET wrapper DLL that does support COM interop to VB6 and then call the wrapper from VB. you can then choose to late or early bind like this.

[This question has a suitable answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667397/accessing-dynamically-loaded-dll-with-loadlibrary-in-visual-basic-6)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my question on

http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-227349.html

```
If it is a standard DLL (you'll notice you can't reference it if you attempt to) 
then you'll have to use LoadLibrary, GetProcAddress to get a function pointer. 
Since VB has no good means of calling a function pointer, you'd then pass that 
pointer off to a dll in a language that can call one.
```