# how call dll export function in vb6?

Tags: dll, vb6, getprocaddress

how can call dll export faunction in vb6?
CallWindowProc have limtied in paramet.
in example how call this fanction ?

```
Dim lb As Long, pa As Long
lb = LoadLibrary("wininet.dll")
pa = GetProcAddress(lb, "InternetOpen")
```

Comment: Why would you want to use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress instead of just declaring the function to access it?

Comment: @vincent-g Checking vb language restrictions

Comment: CallWindowProc is expected to be used for hooking/subclassing, not invoking some random function. Calling a dll function in vb6/vba is expected to be done using a Declare statement.

Comment: @vincent-g  There is no way to do this?

Comment: May be @user2522767 needs to load dll dinamically at run time?

Comment: @user2522767 AFAIK no other possibility. Using `CallWindowProc` is more a hack than other thing (See [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667397/accessing-dynamically-loaded-dll-with-loadlibrary-in-visual-basic-6) ).

Comment: @TSion.D.P
yes.but can not find anyway

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing dynamically loaded DLL (with LoadLibrary) in Visual Basic 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667397/accessing-dynamically-loaded-dll-with-loadlibrary-in-visual-basic-6)

Comment: VB6 calls those lines of code on your behalf. You set it up with a `declare` statement in VB6. Also there is no call of that name. It will have an `A` for ANSI suffix or a `W` for unicode suffix. Calling API calls you call the A with a string or the W with the first element of a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

These definitions are copied from pinvoke.net and modified the variable types for vb6.

*I have not tested this code.*

```
Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG = 0  ' use registry configuration
Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT = 1 ' direct to net
Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY = 3  ' via named proxy
Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG_WITH_NO_AUTOPROXY = 4 ' prevent using java/script/INS

Declare Function InternetOpen Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetOpenA" ( _
    ByVal sAgent As String, _
    ByVal lAccessType As Long, _
    ByVal sProxyName As String, _
    ByVal sProxyBypass As String, _
    ByVal lFlags As Long) As Long
```

Usage:

```
Dim hInet As Long
hInet = InternetOpen("HttpAgent", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, _
  "", "", 0)
If hInet = 0 Then 
  'Return or handle a False return status
End If
```